# RMStore restoring a single transaction with hosted download

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, rmstore

How do i use RMStore to re-download (restore) an single in app purchase with out redownloading all in app purchases?

the following code will re-download all in-app purchases but this is not practical for cases where multiple in-app purchases with large downloads have been made:

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{
    NSLog(@"Transactions restored");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
}];
```

i'd like to do something like

```
[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionWithIdentifier:productIdentifier];
```

Is this possible. how would i do this?

Comment: Can you describe the use case in which you want to restore a single transaction? I can´t see how that would be necessary.

Comment: I want the same feature, when user buy product and then delete content, user should see "Download" button, and when he pressed it, I need get SKPaymentTransaction from productIdentifier and start downloading

Comment: What ChikabuZ said. on a related note (i know this should be a separate question), the opposite use case would also be good. being able to purchase without downloading - i've also got a use case where i have in app purchases that have dependencies on other inapp purchases. so id like to be able to allow them to purchase to satisfy the dependencies but not download the content.

Comment: Content and transactions should be dealt with separately. It appears you both want to restore content, not the transaction. If you're using Apple hosted downloads, I believe this is tricky. You might want to host content yourselves to have more control.

Comment: Anyone got a solution to this? Same issue. Want to restore a purchase but it's forcing a download of all hosted content for past purchases. Hundreds of mb of stuff I don't need.